# How do I get IPv4 of the host OS(Windows) from the guest OS(Ubuntu) in Oracle Virtualbox?

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, oracle

My Windows host IP is 192.168.1.112 as connected to the router.
And I've installed Ubuntu 18.04 in Oracle Virtualbox and its IP is 10.0.2.15(NAT Adapter)

I want to get the host IP address in the Ubuntu's terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You could install netdiscover

> sudo apt install netdiscover

after the installation just enter "sudo netdiscover" and it will give every IP of you LAN with the hostname and MAC Address

Comment: No,  it won't because it's a VM.

Comment: Try to run "sudo dhclient"

Comment: The OP is running  a NATed VM.